# Find Text Value, Offset Row, Enter Formula, and Copy

Tags: excel, vba

In my macro, I have a Excel Table.

Step 1: Find the text: "All Other" that will always be in Column C.

Step 2: Enter a Sum formula in row over in Column D - (0,1).

Step 3: Sum the Unknown Range starting with Column D, 3 Rows down, Referencing Column A for Last Row of Data.

Step 4: Copy the Formula and paste it into Column E - (0,2)?

The below doesn't seem to work, because the Sum Formula starts in Column C, 3 Rows Down, instead of Column D.

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim cOther As Range
Dim DataLastRow As Long

For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
With Ws
 If .Index <> 1 Then

 DataLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 Set cOther = .Range("C:C").Find("All Other", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

 cOther.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=SUM(" & cOther.Offset(3, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(DataLastRow, 3).Address & ")"


 cOther.Offset(0, 1).Copy cOther.Offest(0, 2)

End If
End With
Next Ws
```

Example:
In Sheet2, "All Other" is in (3, 20).
  `DataLastRow` does = 310

When I hover over beginning of the formula line is shows: `cOther.Offset(0,1).Formula = $C$23:$D$310`

However, when I hover over `cOther.Offset(3,1).Address` is says: `=$D$23`

The `cOther.Offset(0, 1).Copy cOther.Offest(0, 2)` is giving Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: change `.Cells(DataLastRow, 3)` to `.Cells(DataLastRow, 4)`

Comment: you have a typo in the second Offset: `cOther.Offset(0, 1).Copy cOther.Offest(0, 2)`

Comment: Thanks for the second set of eyes!